# Can't purchase more VS Team Services Users despite already removed Spending Limit

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azureportal

I have a monthly Azure Credit account, and I know I can't purchase more users using the Azure Credits. I would like to purchase them normally. I have already disabled my Spending Limit. However, i am still unable to purchase. Please help.

Comment: I would recommend reaching out to Azure Support for this. IMHO, this question is not fit for this place (and will most likely be closed). HTH.

Comment: Are you the administrator or Co-administrator of the Azure subscription and account owner or Team Services project collection administrator of the VSTS account? And can you share more details about what issue you have? Not just unable to purchase.